# How to put different columns together in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table like what is showing in the picture. How could I make a file like

```
BP1~PT1~CLM1~P1~P2~P3~**CLM2~P1~P2~|~PT2~CLM1~P1~P2~**~CLM2~P1~\n
BP2~PT1~CLM1~P1~PT2~CLM1~P1~\n
```

Thank you

[image]

Comment: The only way I can see to do this is using a cursor to step through the data and build the string. What have you tried so far? This is my usual fishing comment to ascertain whether the poster is seriously interested in pursuing a solution.

Comment: Also can you post the actual SQL that results in the table that you posted a picture of something like `SELECT BillingProvider, ... FROM ATable`

Comment: This is something I would do outside of sql server. get the entire result set into a program and use loops over the result set in whatever programming language you work with to generate the desired string and save it into a file.

Comment: Actually, I am still generating this table based on an EDI file. Some table content needs to be corrected in my database and has to converted back to EDI format after the correction. Even though I can converted it back to EDI by JAVA, I still want to know if there is a SQL way to do it. Thanks